# Adding pause between audio tracks in VLC

Tags: audio, vlc

I am interested in inserting pause of 2 second between tracks. This [link](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=70438) explains procedure for inserting pause of definite length between two tracks, but it is not clear to me what should I modify or add to the code. I have opened playlist (.xspf extension) in notepad and is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_3.mp3</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_1.mp3</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_2.mp3</location>
            <duration>576</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>2</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
    </trackList>
    <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:item tid="0"/>
            <vlc:item tid="1"/>
            <vlc:item tid="2"/>
    </extension>
</playlist>
```

Can someone explain me what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
<track>
    <location>vlc://pause:2</location>
    <duration>792</duration>
    <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
    <vlc:id>ID</vlc:id>
    </extension>
</track>
```

is to inserted between `<track> <\track>` where pause is required and the variable ID to be updated sequentially; and in the bottom the list `<vlc:item tid="ids"/>` must changed accordingly.

Following code will insert two second pause after *File_3* and *File_1*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playlist xmlns="http://xspf.org/ns/0/" xmlns:vlc="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/ns/0/" version="1">
    <title>Playlist</title>
    <trackList>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_3.mp3</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>0</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>vlc://pause:2</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>1</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_1.mp3</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>2</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>vlc://pause:2</location>
            <duration>792</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>3</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
        <track>
            <location>file:///C:/Folder1/File_2.mp3</location>
            <duration>576</duration>
            <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
                <vlc:id>4</vlc:id>
            </extension>
        </track>
    </trackList>
    <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:item tid="0"/>
            <vlc:item tid="1"/>
            <vlc:item tid="2"/>
            <vlc:item tid="3"/>
            <vlc:item tid="4"/>
    </extension>
</playlist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a void file with, for example, Audacity. On Linux, you may also put a dot "." before the file name, so it will remain hidden in the list.